# How to use replicate to generate a matrix

Tags: haskell

I was curious how to use replicate in Haskell to create a list of integers that repeated a set of numbers. This is for a homework and the rules kind of confuse me to begin with but essentially I'm wanting to create a list that is 1..9 9 times, so 81 integers in this list just 1..9 each time. I've tried a few things upon google search, the thing that got me the closest was

```
zipWith' (replicate 9 1) [1..]
```

Which seemed close to what I was going for but it spiraled out of control and I'm not sure how to reset it back to 1 I suppose

My first thought was something super simple as in

```
replicate 9 [1..9]
```

Which seems very very close to what I need, however it's a list of lists and I'm not sure how to make just a list of all those numbers. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To flatten a list of lists, you can use `concat`:

```
concat (replicate 9 [1..9])
```

Another option is to make an infinite list of `[1..9, 1..9, 1..9, …]` using `cycle` and take the first 81 elements:

```
take 81 (cycle [1..9])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 6):

Since there is a semigroup over lists, you can use `stimes` to repeat it some fixed number of times.

> [`stimes`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.21/base-4.9.1.0/Data-Semigroup.html#v:stimes) `:: (Semigroup a, Integral b) => b -> a -> a`
>
> Repeat a value n times.

```
stimes 9 [1..9]
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list of lists `[[Int]]`, and you want to make a simple list `[Int]` out of it. [Ask `Hoogle`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5BInt%5D%5D+-%3E+%5BInt%5D)! The first result is

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```